# SSRS 2008R2 - Tick Marks on bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, label

I have been trying to accomplish something rather simple, but it is proving extremely frustrating and difficult.  I am sure the answer is apparent and possibly even staring me in the face.

I am making a chart in SSRS 2008 R2, the data is coming over ODBC from an AS400.  I have one single column of data that I need.  This data looks like this (string):

```
000000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000
```

Each of these 60 characters in this string represents what *should* have been in its own column, and each char here can be a 1 or a 0.  I cannot change the schema though, I must use this data as-is.  I need to do a total sum of ~1000 rows, with each character acting like a column.  So each sum will be between 0 - 1000.

I have managed to separate this data into 60 columns using select substring as column, from the SQL side.

I managed to sum, and get each column (Sum of) to represent a bar on a SSRS chart.

[IMG showing how I am adding these columns to the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIti8.jpg)
[image]

I want to have each bar have a number underneath it, representing it's column name, or simply the number of that column - starting from 1-60.  How can I accomplish this?

This is all I want and I am done (I have no columns which will help in category or series):

[Numbers I want to see (added using paint.net)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwbaS.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your Horizontal Axis Properties.
2. Go to the Axis Options tab.
3. Set the Axis type to Scalar.
4. Set the Interval type to Number.
5. Set the Interval to 1.

In other words, you're telling it to show every whole number on the axis.

Comment: This did not work for me on this report, but it does on other reports.  I think since I am using 60 different individual series, it does not like what I am trying to do.  With a single series from a normal style of report - your solution works perfect.  But when I am adding 60 different columns (each is it's own bar in the graph), each one as a series, I cannot get any X axis to behave properly.  Thanks for your effort and time though.  I think I am just going to paste an image with the scale or some individual text boxes with the scale...